# array to dynamic list c#

Tags: c#, linked-list

For my Programming class I have to manually make  a Linked list and some methods for it, I need to insert Projects sorted,the code which I have written is :

```
        public bool Insert(Project project)
    {
        bool gotInserted = true;
        if (IsInList(project) == true)
        {
            gotInserted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Node tmp = this._head;
            this._head = new Node();
            this._head.Project = project;
            this._head.Next = tmp;
            //SortList(); //is commented, because this method causes problems
         }
        return gotInserted;
```

Can I have a better method to insert the nodes sorted?

Node-Class:

```
public class Node
{
    Project _project;
    Node _next;  

    public Project Project
    {
        get { return _project; }
        set { _project = value; }
    }

    public Node Next
    {
        get { return _next; }
        set { _next = value; }
    }
```

Sorry for poor grammar, i am Austrian, and in my freetime i don't usually have to think in english.

Comment: You mean you have a Linked List now. Inorder to have it sorted you first have to look for the appropriate part to insert. Why not use a List<>?

Comment: I'm guessing since this is for a class, he has to create his own homebrewed version of `List<>` rather than just use the existing framework.

Comment: If this code works, but the sorting causes problems, show the sorting code and the problems it causes.

Comment: We have no idea what the `Project` or `Node` types look like. We also have no idea how you want them sorted. Does the `Project` type of a `Name` property and you want them alphabetized or what?

Comment: sorry to forget mentioning it, but i'm not allowed to use list<>

Comment: my sorting is rather complicated, i write the list into an array, use bubblesort, and change it back to a list, and this is where it fails. but i would like a better sort.

Comment: You should describe the project class and what the sorting criteria is. Then read the answer from @ps06756 and you have your solution.

Comment: thanks for the help, a friend of mine has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorting after every insertion is very ineffective, instead try to insert each node in a sorted manner.

Inserting in a sorted manner requires 2 steps:-

1) Determining the position of the node:-

2)Inserting the node.

First find the correct position(using a while loop) and then insert it at the relevant place.

forex

1 -> 2 -> 5 > 6 is the list.

You have to insert 3 in there.

1)Find the relevant place (ie 2)
2)Create a new Node
3)Make newNode's Next property equal to `Next` property of 2.
4)Assign `Next` Property of 2 to newNode .

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through your list starting at the beginning and check each item. When you find an item that is larger, then you should insert your item at that point and then make your new item point to that old one.

You don't want to insert the item and then try to sort it. You need to find the correct insertion point first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine a field or a property in the Project class that you can sort on (some  id for example), or make a method that uses multiple variables, that way you can  check for the condition and determine the right spot to insert as Rvdk stated.

```
public bool Insert(Project project)
{
bool gotInserted = true;

if (IsInList(project) == true)
{
    gotInserted = false;
}
else
{
    Node tmp = this._head;

    while(project.id < tmp.Project.id)
    {
        tmp = tmp.Next;
    }

    this._head = new Node();
    this._head.Project = project;
    this._head.Next = tmp;
}

return gotInserted;
}
```